# Unable to create a dynamic dropdown in property panel in pcf template dataset

Tags: powerapps-component-framework

I want to fetch data from an array and show it in property panel as a drop down.

Used Of-type enum, but unable to add dynamic value in it. Tried using JS as well by targeting the class name of the drop down created by property of-type enum and appending  in it using a loop but it isn't working in the data verse upon importing as  it is unable to find the class of the object. Is there any other way through which I can do this?